# Populating Thymeleaf rows, with one of column referenced to another table(Database).Need another column of referenced Table to display

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am beginner with springboot. I came across a situation.Ok, let me give table structure before I explain.

**Expenses**

```
expensesId, categories,
```

**Categories**

```
categoryId, categoryname
```

> Expenses table is referring to category table with **categoryId**.

I am able to populate `datatable` with `expensesList` that was sent from a controller to view successfully. But my problem is I get `columnid` in populated but I wish to populate that column with `categoryname` instead. I thought for possible solutions for some time and I come up with stupid Idea using If the condition in `thymeleaf` of mapping `categoryId` with `categoryName` but I don't wish to go for that part as I can have more categories growing in future and code is difficult to maintain.

I could really use some help on this.

[Link to git project](https://github.com/mars-boy/monitor)

[expensespage link](https://github.com/mars-boy/monitor/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/common/expensespage.html)

[expenses controller link](https://github.com/mars-boy/monitor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marsboy/monitor/controller/ExpensesController.java)

Please do provide links if a solution is already available which I missed during my google search on this issue.

Apologies for bad english for Title part as I cannot squeeze question further.

Comment: may I know reason for Downvote? Cause I dont see any valid reason for so. I posted question and having getting no attention I tried for various solutions and I posted the solution I found and hoping someone can find some benefit from it moreover this question was not a duplicate too.

Answer (score 0):

I just added category object containing Id and name to every expenses object in 
Expenses Object List and passed to controller. Now I can directly use CategoryName in View with Thymeleaf as follows

```
<td th:text="${expense.categories.categoryname}"></td>>
```

What I changed in controller.

**Before**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/expenses")
    public String toExpensesPage(Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = monitorService.getUserByUserName(authentication.getName()).get(0);
        List<Categories>  categoriesList = monitorService.getAllCategories();
        model.addAttribute("expenses",new Expenses());
        if(categoriesList != null) {
            model.addAttribute("categories",categoriesList);
        }
        List<Expenses> expensesList = monitorService.getAllExpensesActive(user.getUserid());
        model.addAttribute("expensesList",expensesList);
        return "common/expensespage";
    }
```

**To.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/expenses")
public String toExpensesPage(Model model) {
    Map<Integer,String> categoryMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = monitorService.getUserByUserName(authentication.getName()).get(0);
    /* getting Category List This contains both categoryId and categoryname */
    List<Categories>  categoriesList = monitorService.getAllCategories();
    /* Using hashmap to map id to name  so we dont need to iterate categoryList or call to database with category Id..*/
    for(int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size();i++){
        categoryMap.put(categoriesList.get(i).getCategoryid(),

categoriesList.get(i).getCategoryname());
        }
        model.addAttribute("expenses",new Expenses());
        if(categoriesList != null) {
            model.addAttribute("categories",categoriesList);
        }
        List<Expenses> expensesList = monitorService.getAllExpensesActive(user.getUserid());
        /*Assigning category object to expenses object*/
        for(int i = 0; i < expensesList.size();i++){
            Categories categories = new Categories();
            categories.setCategoryid(expensesList.get(i).getCategories().getCategoryid());
            categories.setCategoryname(categoryMap.get(expensesList.get(i).getCategories().getCategoryid()));
            expensesList.get(i).setCategories(categories);
        }
        model.addAttribute("expensesList",expensesList);
        return "common/expensespage";
    }
```

Added Comment's inside code on how I did. Hope someone find it helpful.